# Deserializing JSON with JSON.NET in Windows 8 Store App

Tags: json, microsoft-metro, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize the following JSON into an object in my Win 8 app:

```
{
"success":true,
"pharmacies":[
{
"name":"Test Pharmacy",
"phone":null,
"description":"sample description",
"pharmacyid":"1234567",
"pic":"/1341864197.png",
"address":"211 Warren St., #205",
"city":"Newark",
"state":"NJ",
"zipcode":"07103",
"delivery":true,
"dob_check":false,
"name_check":false,
"can_pickup":true,
"barcode_template":"9999999XX"
}
]
}
```

This is the model I'm using:

```
public class PharmacyList
{
    public List<Pharmacy> pharmacies { get; set; }
}
public class Pharmacy
{
    public string pharmacyid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }


}
```

And here is the code I'm using to de-serialize

```
json = await results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
List<PharmacyList> p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PharmacyList>>(json);
```

I'm getting the following exception:

: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PharmacyHC.Models.PharmacyList]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Am I trying to deserialize into the wrong type or should I format the JSON as it comes back from the API differently?

Comment: To the person who down-voted this post: Please leave a reason why it's not adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the dumb mistake I made. p should have been declared as type PharmacyList instead of a list object since the class declaration for PharmacyList contained a List object already.

```
List<PharmacyList> p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PharmacyList>>(json);
```

it should have been

```
PharmacyList p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PharmacyList>(json);
```